# How to parse a complex Excel document with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I know how to parse Excel documents as per [Read Excel using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485958/read-excel-using-linq) however the following document presents a greater challenge.  It seems this would be very difficult to parse.  Can anyone provide any "best practice" advice in approaching the following (?):

[image]

Comment: B. Why limit yourself to linq? if it would be easier without then why not do that?

Comment: @Sayse I never really thought that it may be easier without using LINQ.  I usually prefer LINQ solutions because they are simpler in my opinion.

Comment: In a lot of cases yes, but I'd say see where you get without first :) you may find with working code, elements where you can easily convert to linq

Comment: Have you taken a look at ClosedXML it has some great parsing tools for excel http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Please describe your "problems" a little bit more detailed.

Comment: @MarcusHaßmann The problem is, in a normal Excel document, you can use the first row as the "header" and all subsequent rows as "data."  But, in this document, I have fields for the country (Australia, China, etc.) -> month (January, February, etc.) -> and all the rows inside.  I am not sure how to parse this document.

Comment: Do you need to do this once or will you need to do this regularly? If doing once, how many sections are there?

Comment: @Brad The document will be uploaded periodically with different data.  Hence, the need to programmatically harvest the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/ which as worked quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I use [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) for (fast!) reading whole Excel sheets.
The result of the following piece of code is a two dimensional array:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
var rowCount = excelSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
var columnCount = excelSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
var range = excelSheet.Range["A1", Type.Missing];
range = range.Resize[rowCount, columnCount];
return (Object[,])range.Value2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure how this helps.  How can I apply this to the question asked?

Comment: You can get the whole content of the sheet with this piece of code and you can work with the array result. You said it is difficult to parse this document. I don't see any problem.