# How to do a 2 criteria vlookup with excel data

Tags: excel, vb.net, vlookup

I have 2 `TextBox` controls where criteria 1 and criteria 2 are passed. The function opens an Excel file provided in the filepath (`destination1`) and in `Sheet2` the vlookup must take col A, col B and return col C value to `textbox3`.

However the error I get is:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled HResult=-2147467261 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there a simple way to use vlookup for searching 2 criterias in VB.NET?

```
Public Sub lookValue()

    Dim cit1 As String
    Dim cit2 As String
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(destination1)
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim userange As Excel.Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    Dim startcell As Excel.Range

    'Finding the dynamic table range in sheet lookup

    sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    startcell = sht.Range("A1")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = sht.Cells(startcell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column

    'select range
    userange = sht.Range(startcell, sht.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))

    'Constraints from 2 textboxs given in userform
    If TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text <> "" Then

        cit1 = TextBox1.Text
        cit2 = TextBox2.Text
        'calling vlookup function by passing the lookup range from above, return value in col C if col A in excel sheet(lookup)
        'has textbox 1.value & col B in excel sheet(lookup) has textbox2.value
        TextBox3.Text = Two_Con_Vlookup(userange, 3, cit1, cit2)

        'xlApp.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(raw, userange, 1, False))

    End If

End Sub

Function Two_Con_Vlookup(Table_Range As Excel.Range, Return_Col As Long, Col1_Fnd As String, Col2_Fnd As String) As Object

    Dim rCheck As Excel.Range, bFound As Boolean, lLoop As Long
    Dim xlmath As Excel.WorksheetFunction
    'On Error Resume Next

    rCheck = Table_Range.Columns(1).Cells(1, 1)

    With xlmath

        For lLoop = 1 To .CountIf(Table_Range.Columns(1), Col1_Fnd)

            rCheck = Table_Range.Columns(1).find(Col1_Fnd, rCheck, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, SearcbOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)

            If UCase(rCheck(1, 2)) = UCase(Col2_Fnd) Then

                bFound = True

                Exit For

            End If

        Next lLoop

    End With

    If bFound = True Then

        Two_Con_Vlookup = rCheck(1, Return_Col)

    Else

        Two_Con_Vlookup = "Match Not Found"

    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to query on the table you need are using the vlookup in and a 2nd query on the vlookup table, then combine the join the two queries.  Run a loop for each query result to output your excel file column.

Comment: Since I am new to this coding world. It takes time for me to understand the solution. Thanks for the reply I will learn LINQ in vb.net

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485958/read-excel-using-linq.  I think you'll be surprised at the simplicity and easy of implementation into your current project.